# The list of unicode unusual characters

Tags: unicode

Where can I get the complete list of all unicode characters that doesn't behave as simple characters. Examples: character 0x0363 (won't be printed without another one before), character 0x0084 (does weird things when printed). I need just a raw list of such unusual characters to replace them with something harmless to avoid unwanted output effects. Regular characters (those who not in this list) should use exactly one character place when printed (= cursor moved +1 to the right), should not depend on previous or next characters, and should not affect printing style in any way.

Edit because of multiple comments:
I have some unicode string, usually consists of "usual" characters like 0x20-0x7E or cyrillic letters. Also, there are a lot of other unicode characters that are usual and may be safely assumed as having strlen() = 1. The string is printed on the terminal and I should know the resulting position of the cursor. I don't want to use some complex and non-stable libraries to do that, i want to have simplest possible logic to do that. Every problematic  character may be replaced with U+0xFFFD or something like "<U+0363>" (ASCII string with its index instead of character itself). I want to have a list of "possibly-problematic" characters to replace. It is acceptable to have some non-problematic characters in this list too, but not much.

Comment: This question is not as well-specified as you may think it is, or put differently: when dealing with Unicode, "unusual" is the norm. There are *many* characters that are "normal" in some sense and still influence how the stuff before and after them is rendered (for example basically every Arabic letter falls into this category). Then there are multiple codepoints that represent multiple distinct glyphs, such as U+FB03 which is the ffi ligature or U+2168 which is the roman numeral 9 (basically IX).

Comment: Don't forget the right-to-left characters, national flags consisting of multiple code points, emoji modifiers etc.

Comment: Plus, "affect printing style in any way" is a layout issue, which is explicitly not handled by Unicode. Ligatures, despite existing in Unicode, are almost always a font issue. Different fonts have different ligatures, and so different characters may impact "printing style."

Comment: Also don't forget about platform-specific ZWJ sequences. ‍ displays as 2 grapheme  clusters on most platforms (a cat followed by glasses), but on recent Windows versions it displays as a single hipster cat.

Comment: @RobNapier: good point. The ligatures (and other pre-combined characters) in Unicode only exist to provide round-trip compatibility with legacy encodings. In a "perfect Unicode world" `ä` would never be represented using U+00E4, but only using a U+0061 (a) and U+0308 (combining diacritic).

Comment: So we can help you, can you give some more background on what problem you're trying to solve, and what rendering engine and font you plan to use? As asked, there is no answer to this. There is no definition of "simple" character in Unicode. What you can explore are Unicode character properties, which may provide some of the things you're looking for (for example, it defines a class of "combining characters"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property How you query the properties depends on your language and libraries.

Comment: Unicode site has extensive documentation on characters, and there is also various files about properties of data. So yes: you have most of information (and often some font related problems with different scripts). Note: Korean is a very different language in Unicode implementation, and CJK is also different (so also in different files in Unicode database). Unicode is complex, and you question is too generic

Comment: @JoachimSauer I want to deal with simple characters and escape all others, don't much care about them. All I need is the list of the "others" to escape.

Comment: What I (and many others here) are trying to tell you that there is no definite answer to what is "a simple character" in Unicode. And according to most definitions of it, if that's all that you allow, you will necessarily exclude a wide range of widely-used scripts (basically everything that isn't written using a small number of "normal alphabets"). I think it would be more honest to just say "we don't support Unicode, pick from those limited characters".

Comment: Unicode itself contains a vast number of lists of characters, including characters with specific properties. If you can rearticulate this into "I want a list of characters with properties X and Y" then it's easy, but the trivial answer then is "use the Unicode properties" by whatever means they are exposed in your language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple algorithm for this. You'll likely need a complex, but extremely stable library: [libicu](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/), or something based on it. Basically every other library that does this kind of work is based on libicu, which is maintained by the Unicode organization.

If you don't want to use the official library (or something based on their library), you'll need to parse the [Unicode Character Database](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/) yourself. In particular, you need to look at [Character Properties](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr23/), and parse the files in the [UCD](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/).

I believe you're asking for [Bidi_Class](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedBidiClass.txt) (i.e. "direction") to be Left_To_Right, [Canonical_Combining_Class](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedCombiningClass.txt) to be Not_Reordered, and [Joining_Type](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedJoiningType.txt) to be Non_Joining.

You probably also want to check the [General_Category](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedGeneralCategory.txt) and avoid M* (Marks) and C* (Other).

This should work for some Emoji, but this whole approach will break a lot of emoji that look simple and are not. Most famously: ❤️, which is two "characters," not one. You may want to filter out [Emoji](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt). As a simple starting point, you may want to restrict yourself to the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), which are code points 0000-FFFF. Anything above this range is, almost by definition, rare or unusual. The BMP does include some emoji, but most emoji (and all new emoji) are outside the range.

Remember that the glyphs for single characters can still have radically different widths, even in nominally fixed-width fonts. For example,  (U+12219 CUNEIFORM SIGN LUGAL OPPOSING LUGAL) is a completely "normal" character in the way you're describing. It is left-to-right. It doesn't depend on or influence characters around it (it's non-combining and non-joining). Its "length in characters" is 1. Its glyph is also extremely wide in most fonts and breaks a lot of layout. I don't know anything in the Unicode database that would warn you of this, since "glyph width" is entirely a function of fonts, not characters, and Unicode explicitly does not consider fonts. (That said, most of the most problematic characters are outside the BMP. Probably the most common exception is Ǆ, but many fixed-width fonts have a narrow glyph for it: `Ǆ`.)

```
Let's write some cuneiform in a fixed-width font.
Normally, every character should line up with a character above.
Here: . See how these characters don't align correctly?
Not only is it a very wide glyph, but its width is not even a multiple.
At least not in my font (Mac Safari 15.0).
But Ǆ is ok.
```

Also remember that there are multiple ways to encode the same "character." For example, é can be a "simple" character (U+00E9), or it can be two characters (U+0065, U+0301). So in some cases é may print in your scheme, and in others it won't. I suspect this is fine for your problem, but if it isn't, you're going to need to apply a [normalization form](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) (likely NFC).

Comment: I think the "glyph width" problem is not a big deal, and also it is automatically solved when using fixed-width fonts. As for the other statements, this is exactly what I asked for. I'll try to parse UCD, and may be the support of some simple non-usual properties is not as difficult as I thought before.

Comment:  renders just fine as a normal-sized character in MS Terminal ... in the sense that the console / font realizes there's no way to fit it and instead crams two dots in the same space.